# Select ValueA where [count(ValueB) > 2 and the counted rows share ValueC]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table such as this:

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
| AggregateId | TransactionDate | EventName |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 123abc      | 2021-08-21      | EventA    |
| 123abc      | 2021-08-21      | EventA    |
| 123abc      | 2021-08-21      | EventB    |
| 123abc      | 2021-09-15      | EventA    |
| 456xyz      | 2021-08-21      | EventA    |
| 456xyz      | 2021-08-21      | EventA    |
| 456xyz      | 2021-08-21      | EventC    |
| 456xyz      | 2021-08-30      | EventA    |
| 789dfg      | 2021-08-30      | EventA    |
| ....        | ...             | ...       |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

I want to get a list of all AggregateIds that have more than one EventA on the same date, such is the case on the row 1,2 and 5,6.

Expected Output:

```
+-------------+
| AggregateId |
+-------------+
| 123abc      |
| 456xyz      |
+-------------+
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work at all.

```
SELECT 
t.AggregateId
from Table1 t1 inner join Table1 t2 on t1.CreditId = t2.CreditId
where  t1.TransactionDate = t2.TransactionDate
group by t1.creditid
having count(case t.EventName when 'EventA' then 1 else null end) > 1
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Edited to meet the requirements now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.AggregateId, 
from Table1
where t.EventName = 'EventA'
group by t.AggregateId, t.TransactionDate
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Well that was easy, haha. Cheers!